# Validate JSON in Play framework without JSPath

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have pre-defined class `MyClass` the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "key1": [
      // Objects of MyClass
  ],

  "key2": [
      // Objects of MyClass
  ],

  "key3": [
      // Objects of MyClass
  ]
}
```

`key1, key2, key3` are optional (at least one must present but I do not need to validate it)
According to the Play framework documentation I need to do the following:

```
implicit val myClassReads: Reads[] = (
  (JsPath \ "key1").read[List[MyClass]] and
  (JsPath \ "key2").read[List[MyClass]] and
  (JsPath \ "key3").read[List[MyClass]]
)
```

But this approach has some disadvantages :

1. The data type of `key1, key2, key3` is always `MyClass`). Repeating `read[MyClass]` seems redundant.
2. What if the JSON schema changes in away that there are `key1, key2, ... key100` ? The code becomes very messy.

How can I write a custom validator that apply `read[MyClass]` to all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Play Json 2.8.x, you can just do:

```scala
val result = json.validate[Map[String, List[MyClass]]]
```

---

> Is it possible to validate whether the JSON keys are in ALLOWED_KEYS: List[String] with your approach?

You can also use another type for the key of the `Map`, as long as you define a `KeyReads` instance for that type. So you could use an Enum, with only a limited number of possible values. Or you can use refinement types (e.g. using the "refined" library) and so on.

The easiest way to restrict the possible values of the keys is to check the resulting Map after conversion:

```scala
val ALLOWED_KEYS = Set("key1", "key2", ...)

val result = json.validate(
  Reads.verifying[Map[String, List[MyClass]]](_.keySet.subsetOf(ALLOWED_KEYS))
)
```

or you can also check the keys upfront if you want:

```scala
val result = json.validate(
  Reads.verifying[JsObject](_.keys.subsetOf(ALLOWED_KEYS))
    .andThen(Reads.of[Map[String, List[MyClass]]])
)
```

Comment: thank, that solved my problem. Is it possible to validate whether the JSON keys are in `ALLOWED_KEYS: List[String]` with your approach?

Comment: @KhaNguyễn yes, that is possible. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
 def convertJsonToListModel[T](json: JsValue)(implicit reads: Reads[T]): List[T] = {
      val conversionResult: JsResult[List[T]] = json.validate[List[T]]
      conversionResult match {
        case s: JsSuccess[List[T]] => s.get
        case e: JsError => e.get
      }
 }
```

Comment: I think this does not even compile. The type of `e.get` is not `List[T]`.

Comment: @cbley "I think" :/ . Well this is the actual code I use in my application for years now....

Comment: You're right. It compiles. I was a bit distracted by that code since I would never call `.get` on a `JsError` since that throws an exception. Your code is just a complicated way of calling `conversionResult.get` or `json.as[List[T]]` actually.

Answer (score 0):

Play JSON has automatic format derivation for product type's (e.g. case classes).
More details you can find in the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaJsonAutomated
I guess in your case this would like something like next:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class MyClass(value: String)

object MyClass {
 implicit format =  Json.format[Resident]
}

case class MyClassContainer(key1: List[MyClass], key2: List[MyClass], key3: List[MyClass])

object MyClassContainer {
 implicit format =  Json.format[MyClassContainer]
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.